# Graph API returns wrong POST_ID with Exception 803

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

A Graph API query to me/home returns all posts from the logged in users newsfeed. In some cases, the results return a post where multiple users have posted on a single users timeline, for example, to wish the user on his Birthday.

To make it clear a bit further: Users **A** and **B** wrote on **Z's** timeline for his birthday.

The entire applications works as it should. However, in cases like the example above, the post_id is wrong. In the above example for instance, it returns the "id" as **0_10150710912072539**. Now from a lot of reading, and the fact that the app force closes when the user clicks to comment or something, I know the post ID is wrong. Is there a known fix for this?

Any guidance on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, those posts with post_id "0_XXXXXXXXXXX" are dummy roll-up posts you can't interact with. You could filter any posts that begin this way, which would be the easy fix.

As a best practice, you should be looking for `stream.comments.can_post == true` on each post before your app tries to post a comment if you are using FQL, or for the presence of an  `action` where name == 'Comment' and a link is present using the API. This will prevent your users from trying to post comments where they have been disallowed.

The posts in my stream that are roll_up events or items from someone I've subscribed to, but am not friends with all have `comments.can_post == false` and no Actions.

Comment: So I suppose, I must filter and hide such entries entirely. Because the users they see it, they will click it. And that's not good. And although it seems simple, my current implementation will turn out to be quite a pain in the rear. Thanks for your help nonetheless. It does give me a way to get it done. :-)